# Javascript posting to form - won't work if field is hidden

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I read the advice on a similar question and I followed it.  I am posting a value from javascript to a form to be passed to a PHP.  Thing is it all works perfectly if I pass the value to a textarea field but not a hidden field.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="updatepage.js"></script>
<head>

<body onload="loadbio()">
<form action="http://localhost/restricted/update.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenbio" name="oldbio">      <!-- Hidden to pass to PHP  -->
Biography: <br /><textarea id="bio" rows="8" cols="60" name="newbio"></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function loadbio () {
$("#bio").load('randomperson.html #biobox p') 
setTimeout (function () {
    var biotopass = $("#bio").val();
    $.post("biochange.html", { oldbio: biotopass });
    }, 200);
}
```

PHP

```
<html>
<body>
Old Bio: <?php echo $_POST["oldbio"]; ?><br />
New Bio: <?php echo $_POST["newbio"]; ?><br />
</body>
</html>
```

So loadbio() goes out and pulls up the old biography out of a file and posts it to biochange.html.  The HTML displays the old biography in the text area where the person changes it.
This is where the problem lies, I need to store the value of the old value before it changes.  If I change the hidden input to a textarea, it will get echoed in the PHP.  If I leave it hidden it does not get echoed.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are saying "I want to store some information and not display it". So then why not just store it in JS? Also another errors, if your server takes more than 200ms to return the "load" request the "#bio" will still be empty, why not set your timeout in the "load" functions callback to ensure this error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I've noticed:

1. Your `<input type="hidden" id="hiddenbio" name="oldbio">` has no `value` attribute.
2. With this line `var biotopass = $("#bio").val();` you are actually just grabbing the new bio to send it to the server while you ignore the old bio

So you you are not sending anything and even if you did there wouldn't be anything to send. So, once you gave your hidden input a value, all you need to do is send it as well. There's actually a neat trick to send all elements of a form (so you don't have to update your JS if you change your HTML and it automatically resembles the way a form gets sent normally), change your AJAX call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "biochange.html",
    data: $(form).serialize()
})
```

Comment: please explain to me how ``var biotopass = $("#bio").val();`` is sending anything to the server? lol that is just getting the value from an input and storing in a JS variable.

Comment: @SaintCad no AJAX needed? You're already using AJAX: `$.post("biochange.html", { oldbio: biotopass });` That's an AJAX call.

Comment: @Dustin I am totally aware of what that line does but worded it poorly, thanks for pointing that out, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `.load` loads the data into the `.innerHTML` of the element. For `<textarea>` elements the `.innerHTML` IS the data that is submitted in forms, where as `<input>` the `value` attribute is what is submitted in forms.

So that explains why it works with a `<textarea>` but not an `<input>`.

To fix this use `.get` instead of `.load`:

```
$.get("randomperson.html #biobox p", function(x){
  $("#oldbio, #newbio").val(x);
});
```

Where your "#oldbio" is hidden

Answer (score -1):

You're not posting `newbio`. In this line:

```
$.post("biochange.html", { oldbio: biotopass });
}, 200);
```

you're specifying that you only want to post `oldbio`. just adjust it to something like this:

```
function loadbio () {
    $("#bio").load('randomperson.html #biobox p') 
    setTimeout (function () {
        var biotopass = $("#bio").val();
        var hiddenbio = $("#hiddenbio").val();
        $.post("biochange.html", { oldbio: hiddenbio, newbio: biotopass });
        }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why do I need to pass both form values if the person is just going to change it in the form?  Is it an AJAX thing or a form thing?

Comment: yeah so the hidden bio is the old one, the bio to pass is the new one, thus `oldbio: hiddenbio, newbio: biotopass`

Comment: @SaintCad I don't understand your comment. I thought that was exactly what you wanted? Now I'm confused, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I thought I only needed to post oldbio from the javascript because newbio was entered by hand on the html.  Seems like I accidentally did it right irt "newbio" and that was messing me up.